# ASP.NET - What should be included in a Website Installation Checklist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I've been asked to create a website installation checklist for an ASP.NET website. I have included sections that explain how to setup the following:

- Installing ASP.NET Session State
- IIS Configuration
- Running the website installer

What other sections / aspects to consider should generally be included in a checklist for setting up an ASP.NET website?

Comment: Surely it depends on the circumstance and will vary from site to site. It could be anything from scripts that need running on the database to changing the web.config for go live.

Comment: Yes, I realise the setup requirements will vary between different websites but I wanted to find out what sections could generally be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all vary's on your intended audience but here's a few ideas.

- Prerequisites like:

  - .Net framework version.
  - OS, IIS, etc versions
  - Hardware requirements.
- SQL Related config section if applicable.
- App pool configuration
- Security configuration: app pool identity, folder permissions on upload etc, impersonation.
- Web.config: If you have any special AppSettings that need configuring with install.

**EDIT** And this is not really part of a checklist but in an install document including a Troubleshooting section would be a great nice to have

Answer (score 4):

grant permission to network services or the user account ur application is using.

Answer (score 1):

The most important one is sanity checking the application/website and make sure it works.

- If the app write to the file system this should be check as the Network Service needs permissions on the file system to do this.
- Files have been compiled in release and debugging and tracing has been switch off in the web.config